# Installing Iscan for Epson SX425W

Tags: software-installation, dpkg, dependencies, scanner

I downloaded the All-In-One package for the SX420, as this was the one listed for my specific printer, extracted it, and ran intall.sh in a terminal.

The output was as follows:

```
draganglas@draganglas-M570U:~/iscan-bundle-1.0.0.x86.deb$ ./install.sh
(Reading database ... 1279069 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../iscan_2.30.1-1~usb0.1.ltdl7_i386.deb ...
Unpacking iscan (2.30.1-1~usb0.1.ltdl7) over (2.30.1-1~usb0.1.ltdl7) ...
Preparing to unpack .../iscan-data_1.36.0-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking iscan-data (1.36.0-1) over (1.36.0-1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../iscan-network-nt_1.1.1-1_i386.deb ...
Unpacking iscan-network-nt (1.1.1-1) over (1.1.1-1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of iscan:
 iscan depends on iscan-data.
 iscan depends on libgtk2.0-0 (>= 2.14.1).
 iscan depends on libltdl7 (>= 2.2.4).
 iscan depends on libsane (>= 1.0.11-3).
 iscan depends on libusb-0.1-4 (>= 2:0.1.12).

dpkg: error processing package iscan (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up iscan-data (1.36.0-1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of iscan-network-nt:
 iscan-network-nt depends on iscan (>= 2.29.3); however:
  Package iscan is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package iscan-network-nt (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.54ubuntu1.1) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.1+14.04.20140409-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.10.1-0ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for udev (204-5ubuntu20.19) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 iscan
 iscan-network-nt
```

I ran a update but this hasn't solved the issue re dependency problems.

I'm uncertain how to get the required dependencies resolved.

Although my background's in IT, I'm still learning Linux, so go easy on my!

Kindest regards,

James

Comment: OOps! I downloaded the package from [link]http://support.epson.net/linux/en/iscan_c.html[/link].

Comment: From the large red warning sign, as recommended I ran an apt-get install -f, which has uninstalled(?) Iscan - I'm not sure, but it's disappeared from my computer.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing package simple-scan:
`apt-get install simple-scan`

It works for me with XP-202 203 203 Series
Good luck!

Comment: Greetings,

Thank you for the reply, Andrew.

As it happens, I then suffered a GPU problem, which resulted in my having to reinstall Ubuntu. I also had to re-add the printer - it appears to be working fine (both printing and scanning). Whatever had caused it not to work has now been resolved.

This thread can be closed.

Kindest regards,

James